# A connected subset

Tags: general-topology, inequality, connectedness

Let $C$ be the subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that : 
$$0<(x-1)^2+y^2<2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

Is there a simple proof that $C$ is connected? Wolfram shows that this is connected but that doesn’t constitute a proof.

Comment: Given that this looks easy, I spent over half an hour on this, and was lead to realize I'm appearently missing a lot of technical skills in the basics of topology, I'd say this is a great question.